# Asp.net core ExternalLoginCallback error 500

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

i have activated both Google and Facebook external logins, and everything works fine localhost.
the problem is both of the signins return to error 500, when i try to test it in my hosted IIS site.

in google i have set in Authorized redirect URIs
for example:
https://localhost:44309/signin-google
then i have
https://mydomain.gr/signin-google
http://mydomain.gr/signin-google
and i still get this error.
i click sign in with google, i get redirected to the https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth/oauthchooseaccount and when i choose an account i get error 500, and it never hits my ExternalLoginBack, which works in localhost.
any idea why? do i have to publish my App in google.console first in order to make it work?.

in Startup.cs

```
   services.AddAuthentication()

            .AddGoogle(options =>
            {
                options.ClientId = "XXX";
                options.ClientSecret = "XXX";
            })
            .AddFacebook(options =>
            {
                options.AppId = "XXX";
                options.AppSecret = "XXX";
                options.AccessDeniedPath = new PathString("/Home/Index");//"/AccessDeniedPathInfo";
            });
```

and in my login controller.

```
 [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult ExternalGoogleLoginSubmit(string provider, string returnUrl)
    {
        provider = "Google";
        var redirectUrl = Url.Action("ExternalLoginCallback", "Home",
                                new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl });

        var properties =
            _isigninManager.ConfigureExternalAuthenticationProperties(provider, redirectUrl);

        return new ChallengeResult(authenticationScheme: provider, properties);
    }
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult ExternalFacebookLoginSubmit(string provider, string returnUrl)
    {
        provider = "Facebook";
        var redirectUrl = Url.Action("ExternalLoginCallback", "Home",
                                new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl });

        var properties =
            _isigninManager.ConfigureExternalAuthenticationProperties(provider, redirectUrl);

        return new ChallengeResult(authenticationScheme: provider, properties);
    }

    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> ExternalLoginCallback(string returnUrl = null)
    {
        var loginInfo = await _isigninManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
        if (loginInfo == null)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }......}
```

Comment: Could you pls share the stack trace?

Comment: hello,
System.Exception: Correlation failed.
System.Exception: An error was encountered while handling the remote login.
 ---> System.Exception: Correlation failed.
   --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.RemoteAuthenticationHandler`1.HandleRequestAsync() at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Localization.RequestLocalizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)

Comment: Hi @nickD3, are you sure the URL you're starting from in the client is really the same you've configured for your redirect URI (specifically http vs https).

Comment: hi, the problem is in the redirected URI i have first added https:// mydomain.gr/signin-google. and then i got error 400 that it's not added correctly, so then i added http:// mydomain.gr/signin-google (without secure). even tho my site opens with https, in the redirect uri, if i don't add http://... i get this error redirect_uri_mismatch

Comment: Hi, for 400 error. Make sure there is no trailing slash or trailing space when you add it. for example

`https://mydomain.gr/signin-google` is not the same as `https://mydomain.gr/signin-google/`.

Comment: apparently using MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.Lax in my configure file seems to have soled the problem.

Comment: one issue i dont understand is how https: //mydomain.gr/signin-google, returns me error 400 and http ://mydomain.gr/signin-google doesn't. If i want to publish my APP tho, i cannot have http link inside the redirect Urls.